# How to see which functions are executed

Tags: commands, history

When I do something inside Emacs, with the buffer `*Messages*` you get some idea what happened. But it's only if that function is echoing a message for the minibuffer. Then `*Messages*` keeps a record of messages that are echoed.

I remember there was a buffer where all commands were listed that are executed. But I cannot find it back in the Emacs documentation. It displayed also functions that are not echoing any message at all.

Do anyone know about which function I'm talking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This project is also a good alternative:
https://github.com/michael-heerdegen/interaction-log.el

Answer (score 8):

`view-lossage` will show the last few hundred keystrokes. There's also [`command-log-mode`](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode) which records the keystrokes and the command it executed.

Comment: Thanks db48x, I was looking for `view-lossage` I think. Is there another list that keeps record of the latest evaluated commands (so without pressing the keys)?

Comment: There's also https://github.com/michael-heerdegen/interaction-log.el

Comment: @djangoliv, I wished you posted it as answer, so I could validate it as the right answer. Thanks for the link!